# Hebrew: Shamayim. Is it always in plural?

Tags: hebrew

The Hebrew suffix **ים‎** (Yud + Mem)   is a masculine plural.

The word **Shamayim** seems to always end in plural;

1. Genesis 1:1 **הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם** translated; the heavens.
2. Genesis 1:8 **שָׁמָ֑יִם** translated; heaven.
3. Genesis 1:9 **הַשָּׁמַ֙יִם֙** translated; the heavens.
4. Genesis 1:14 **הַשָּׁמַ֔יִם** translated; of the heavens.
5. Genesis 1:15 **הַשָּׁמַ֔יִם** translated; of the heavens.
6. Genesis 1:17 **הַשָּׁמָ֑יִם** translated; of the heavens.
7. Genesis 1:20 **הַשָּׁמָֽיִם** translated; of the heavens.
8. Genesis 1:26 **הַשָּׁמַ֗יִם** translated; of the sky.
9. Genesis 1:28 **הַשָּׁמַ֔יִם** translated; of the sky.
10. Genesis 1:30 **הַשָּׁמַ֜יִם** translated; of the sky.

The word occur over 400 times in the bible but I can't find it in singular form, yet when being translated to singular heaven in Genesis 1:8 it's stil in the Hebrew plural form.

- Are there a Hebrew singular form for this word?

[Source; shamayim Strong's](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/strongs_8064.htm)

Comment: While  ים‎ is usually a masculine plural ending, it does have other uses; most obviously in נָשִׁים _nashim_, "women".

Comment: @ColinFine Thanks! Masculine plural can refer to just this word (Gen 1:1 Noun Masculine Plural) but I also know that names of people (Abarim עברים, Jakim יקים), places (Yerushalayim ירושלים, Mt Olivet הר הזיתים, Egypt מצרים) and foods/fruits (lime ליים) also all places related to sea/lake [ים yam = lake/sea/west] can end in ים without being plural, my question is solely if the plural Shamayim has a singular equivalent.

Comment: Note that _skies_ is a poetic alternative to _sky_ in English. See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29302/using-skies-instead-of-sky

Comment: @ColinFine Yeah you refer to; apaderno "Skies is a poetic/literary word used to mean heaven or heavenly power. The first example sentence could mean reach for heaven." just found this; It should be noted that this Hebrew word, just like “water” (MYM), is always plural. When translating “water” into English, we sometimes use the singular, and sometimes the plural, depending on English grammar usage, and “heavens” should be given this same consideration.

Answer (score 4):

It is what is called a plurale tantum, a word used always in the plural form, but with a singular meaning.

Comment: Thanks "plurale tantum" with m it is..

Comment: @DanielDahlberg. Yes, corrected.

Comment: pluralia tantum are not necessarily singular in meaning

Comment: agree with @Tristan.  Compare with "pelagic" derivative of 'flat, spreading', which contrasts a signified thing with a boundless or indeterminate concept